# Has any possible non-extensive entropy been classified?

Tags: entropy

How many non-extensive entropies do exist? Tsallis, Havrda-Chavrat, Renyi, Kaniadakis, Sharma-Mittal,...

To be more precise, I am wondering if some classification like those of "finite" or Lie groups do exist for uniparametric, biparametric or multiparametric (generally non-extensive) entropy functions (of course, another issue would be their physical applications...)